# EmberJS how to include another Ember.Object file

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

**Situation**
I'm using EmberCLI for my Emberjs project. I created a directory called **"custom_objects"** with a file inside of it called **'person.js'**

**Emberjs Directory**

```
LearningService (my app name)
  + app  
  + components  
  + controllers  
  + custom_objects
     -person.js*
  + helpers
  + models
  + routes
  + services
  + styles
  + templates
```

I am now working inside the components folder on a file called **'person-list.js'**  I want to make the **person.js** file available in **person-list.js** so I typed out the following:

**custom_objects/person.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Object.extend({
   name: 'person'
});
```

**components / person-list.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Person from '../custom_objects/person.js';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

});
```

This is the error I get from the console

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find module `learning-services/custom_objects/person.js`   imported from `learning-services/components/person-list`
```

From the documentation I have read your supposed to use relative path and just include it as shown above.
• I have tried restarting Ember server

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.js` extension is unneeded:

```
import Person from '../custom_objects/person';
```